# sh.exe":mktemp:command not found ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not create a temporary file name

Tags: python, windows-7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I trying to setup virtualenvwrapper in GitBash (Windows 7), but get an error message.

When I run this command: `" $ source /c/Python27/Scripts/virtualenvwrapper.sh"`

Then I get an error: `sh.exe":mktemp:command not found ERROR: virtualenvwrapper could not create a temporary file name.`

Somebody help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had found a solution ,just hope to help someone like me.

download the mktemp.exe , put it into the C:\msys\1.0\bin ,then everything will be ok...

Comment: Didn't work for me though. I installed mktemp, and put it in said directory. The same error shows up :(